# Microsoft Azure sign in stuck in an infinite loading screen

Tags: azure, azure-functions

The errors are as shown in the image... I followed the guide and downloaded the newest tools, but the error still persists... I'm on school wifi right now, and since I'm new to this, I have no idea on how to change Azure's environment variables on an existing project... I cannot sign in in the first place. I was just following through the guide :(

Answer (score 0):

**Please check the below steps if they helps to work around:**

> **Error in Azure portal is**  **HTTP response code 503 Service Unavailable**

This situation happens due to network connectivity or service available issues.

The better approach is to retry the operation and if the issue persists, contact Azure Support as referenced [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/539967/azure-function-app-503-service-unavailable-in-code.html).

**Alternative ways** to solve this error is finding the cause by navigating to `Diagnose and solve problems` to know the root cause of 503 error as there can be multiple reasons for this error.

[image]

Please check the below causes related to `503 error` issue if they helps to work around:

- request taking a long time
- application crashing due to an exception.
- average response time is long
- Function App is also an app service so app service enforces limits on the number of outbound connections

> **Error in Browser / Postman is**  **502 - Web server received an invalid response while acting as a gateway or proxy server.**

As this `502 error`, you were addressed in [MSFT Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/753845/azure-functions-showing-successful-in-logs-but-ret.html).

Normally, `502 error` occurs when `HTTP` is placed instead of `HTTPS` in the connection but I know that the Azure Functions endpoint look like in this format

`http://<APP_NAME>.azurewebsites.net/api/<FUNCTION_NAME>`

And `502 error` occurs when maximum timeout exceeds the value.  Please check the timeout value of the function app and the logs, metrics of requestTime, responseTime in Application Insights and if it is the cause, increase the timeout value.

**References:**

1. [Troubleshooting Reason for a 502 Error](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/1209)
2. [How do I fix this 502 Error on my Azure Function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60376297/how-do-i-fix-this-502-error-on-my-azure-function)