# Azure Functions showing successful in logs but returning 503 error in portal test as well as 502 error in Postman

Tags: azure-functions

Certain functions in my Azure Functions (Consumption Plan) are running well but other functions in the same app are not running correctly. They are showing success in logs but 502 error in browser / client app / postman

Notably , everything these functions needs to do (update cosmos db, send email ) is working , even the logs show success but there is the following error in the portal test

---

**Error in Azure portal is**
**HTTP response code 503 Service Unavailable**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN' 
'http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd'><html 
xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'><head><meta content='text/html; 
charset=utf-8' http-equiv='content-type'/><style type='text/css'>
body {font-family:Arial; margin-left:40px; }img  { border:0 none; }
#content { margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto }#message h2 
{ font-size: 20px; font-weight: normal; color: #000000; margin: 34px 0px 0px 0px }
#message p  { font-size: 13px; color: #000000; margin: 7px 0px 0px0px}
#errorref { font-size: 11px; color: #737373; margin-top: 41px }</style>
<title>Service unavailable</title></head><body><div id='content'><div id='message'>
<h2>Our services aren't available right now</h2><p>We're working to restore all
 services as soon as possible. Please check back soon.</p></div><div id='errorref'>
```

---

**Error in Browser / Postman is**
**502 - Web server received an invalid response while acting as a gateway or proxy server.**

```
There is a problem with the page you are looking for, 
and it cannot be displayed. When the Web server 
(while acting as a gateway or proxy) contacted the upstream content
server, it received an invalid response from the content server.
```

---

What could the problem be?
Also, i noticed that functions that run well do not have any code related to sending emails whereas the ones that do not work have code to send email (and the emails are getting sent correctly)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution Returning any status code in the series 100-199 is what was causing this error .

Comment: As you mentioned the error codes are 502 and 503. But where did the series 100-100 come from?

Comment: Series 100 are the codes that i was trying to return from my function. Instead anyone calling my function was getting code 502/503 and that too after a long wait of 5 to 10 seconds. Now after replacing codes in series 100 with either 200 / 400 /500 series , the code which i intend to return (200/400/500 series)are the ones being received by the caller

Comment: Well obviously that's because all functions (those that worked and those that didn't) ,were returning Object Result so at the time it felt like some other problem, like a longer running func, or app config.   I wrote about 500 series errors , because that is indeed what i was getting. And i wrote it was different in browser and platform because it was indeed different. Not sure what you are trying to say here. To mention what i was returning , i would had to have known , that was the issue. If i knew why would i ask. 100-199 series not being allowed is not documented anywhere, hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

**Please check the below steps if they helps to work around:**

> **Error in Azure portal is**  **HTTP response code 503 Service Unavailable**

This situation happens due to network connectivity or service availability issues.

**The better approach is to retry the operation and if the issue persists, contact Azure Support as referenced [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/539967/azure-function-app-503-service-unavailable-in-code.html).**

Alternative ways to solve this error is finding the cause by navigating to `Diagnose and solve problems to know the root cause of` 503 error` as there can be multiple reasons for this error.

[image]

Please check the below causes related to `503 error` issue if they helps to work around:

- request taking a long time
- application crashing due to an exception.
- average response time is long
- Function App is also an app service so app service enforces limits on the number of outbound connections

> **Error in Browser / Postman is**  **502 - Web server received an invalid response while acting as a gateway or proxy server.**

As this `502 error`, you were addressed in [MSFT Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/753845/azure-functions-showing-successful-in-logs-but-ret.html).

Normally, `502 error` occurs when `HTTP` is placed instead of `HTTPS` in the connection but I know that the Azure Functions endpoint look like in this format

`http://<APP_NAME>.azurewebsites.net/api/<FUNCTION_NAME>`

And `502 error` occurs when maximum timeout exceeds the value.

- Please check the timeout value of the function app and the logs, metrics of requestTime, responseTime in Application Insights and if it is the cause, increase the timeout value.

**References:**

1. [Troubleshooting Reason for a 502 Error](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/1209)
2. [How do I fix this 502 Error on my Azure Function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60376297/how-do-i-fix-this-502-error-on-my-azure-function)